# Custom meta data in static html is not being indexed in Azure search

Tags: azure, search, meta, azure-cognitive-search

I have nearly 500 static html files. all of them have different custom metadata tags like , ,, ,  etc.. I have uploaded the static htmls in to ablob and indexed the blob, as per azure documentation. 
I was successful in searching the index fields  & < description> with relevant content, but for other fields like < region>, ,  it is shown as null. 
I have gone through Azure search documentation extensively. I found that it was ready to map Conten-type specific (HTML) metadata tags, shown in the article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#indexing-documents-along-with-related-data

But could not get appropriate information about the above 3 missing fields. Please help in this

Comment: Looks like parts of your question are missing

Comment: Sorry for that, missing fields are "ms_search_region", "ms_search_locale", "ms_search_formname"

Comment: Please edit your question and add the missing texts

Comment: I have 500 static html files;Each of them have below custom metadata tags ex: "title", "description","ms_search_region","ms_search_locale", "ms_search_formname".I have uploaded the static html s in to a blob and indexed it.I am able to see index fields like "title", "description" with data but for other fields like "ms_search_region", "ms_search_locale", "ms_search_formname"  it is null.I found that it was Content-type specific (HTML) metadata tags, shown in :-
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#indexing-documents-along-with-related-data

Comment: i would like to know how can i get the values of "ms_search_region", "ms_search_locale", "ms_search_formname" for every html in the blob

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Azure Search blob indexer does not support indexing custom metadata tags in HTML files. Please vote for [Custom meta data in static html is not being indexed](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/32547916-custom-meta-data-in-static-html-is-not-being-index) UserVoice suggestion to help us prioritize that feature.

As a workaround, you can add your meta tags to blob metadata, and those will be picked up and indexed by the indexer.

Comment: Hi Shvets,Thanks a lot for the reply.